# Python: Assign a method from one class to an instance of another class

Tags: python

I want to use new.instancemethod to assign a function (aFunction) from one class (A) to an instance of another class (B). I'm not sure how I can get aFunction to allow itself to be applied to an instance of B - currently I am getting an error because aFunction is expecting to be executed on an instance of A.

[Note: I can't cast instance to A using the __class__ attribute as the class I'm using (B in my example) doesn't support typecasting]

```
import new

class A(object):
    def aFunction(self):
        pass

#Class which doesn't support typecasting
class B(object): 
    pass

b = B()
b.aFunction = new.instancemethod(A.aFunction, b, B.__class__)
b.aFunction()
```

This is the error:

```
TypeError: unbound method aFunction() must be called with A instance as first argument (got B instance instead)
```

Comment: The definition of `A` is incorrect - its `aFunction()` method won't work.

Comment: Make that method static.

Comment: Sorry that should read
    def aFunction(self):

I still get the same error though.

Comment: Although I find this question quite interesting, I wonder if it is a good approach for whatever thing you are trying to do...

Comment: @brandizzi: +1, but I also +1'd the question, because it _is_ interesting, and the right answer leads into an interesting part of Python that most people never learn.

Comment: Also, I'm pretty sure you want to use `B`, not `B.__class__` in the `instancemethod`. You want this to be an instance method of the class `B`, not an instance method of the class `type` that the class `B` is an instance of, right? (If not, you probably want `@classmethod` somewehere…)

Comment: @brandizzi The issue is that I'm using PySide.QtGui - when I create a QListWidgetItem, I want to add some functionality to set the font and the colours. In PyQt4 I could just cast the type to by own version of QListWidgetItem using __class__ - however PySide won't allow me to do that. I have a working solution now though, so thanks everyone :)

Comment: In that case, you could have saved a whole lot of trouble by just defining a plain function `setFontAndColors` and monkey-patching the class with it, instead of creating a dummy class just to stick it in as a method, extracting it, building a new method out of it, etc.

Answer (score 6):

`new.instancemethod` takes a function. `A.aFunction` is an unbound method. That's not the same thing. (You may want to try adding a bunch of print statements to display all of the things involved—`A.aFunction()`, `A().aFunction`, etc.—and their types, to help understanding.)

I'm assuming you don't how [descriptors](http://docs.python.org/howto/descriptor.html) work. If you don't want to learn all of the gory details, what's actually going on is that your declaration of `aFunction` within a class definition creates a non-data descriptor out of the function. This is a magic thing that means that, depending on how you access it, you get an unbound method (`A.aFunction`) or a bound method (`A().aFunction`).

If you modify `aFunction` to be a `@staticmethod`, this will actually work, because for a static method both `A.aFunction` and `A().aFunction` are just functions. (I'm not sure that's guaranteed to be true by the standard, but it's hard to see how else anyone would ever implement it.) But if you want "aFunction to allow itself to be applied to an instance of B", a static method won't help you.

If you actually want to get the underlying function, there are a number of ways to do it; I think this is the clearest as far as helping you understand how descriptors works:

```
f = object.__getattribute__(A, 'aFunction')
```

On the other hand, the simplest is probably:

```
f = A.aFunction.im_func
```

Then, calling `new.instancemethod` is how you turn that function into a descriptor that can be called as a regular method for instances of class B:

```
b.aFunction = new.instancemethod(f, b, B)
```

Printing out a bunch of data makes things a lot clearer:

```
import new

class A(object):
  def aFunction(self):
    print self, type(self), type(A)

#Class which doesn't support typecasting
class B(object): 
    pass

print A.aFunction, type(A.aFunction)
print A().aFunction, type(A().aFunction)
print A.aFunction.im_func, type(A.aFunction.im_func)
print A().aFunction.im_func, type(A().aFunction.im_func)

A.aFunction(A())
A().aFunction()

f = object.__getattribute__(A, 'aFunction')
b = B()
b.aFunction = new.instancemethod(f, b, B)
b.aFunction()
```

You'll see something like this:

```
<unbound method A.aFunction> <type 'instancemethod'>
<bound method A.aFunction of <__main__.A object at 0x108b82d10>> <type 'instancemethod'>
<function aFunction at 0x108b62a28> <type 'function'>
<function aFunction at 0x108b62a28> <type 'function'>
<__main__.A object at 0x108b82d10> <class '__main__.A'> <type 'type'>
<__main__.A object at 0x108b82d10> <class '__main__.A'> <type 'type'>
<__main__.B object at 0x108b82d10> <class '__main__.B'> <type 'type'>
```

The only thing this doesn't show is the magic that creates the bound and unbound methods. For that, you need to look into `A.aFunction.im_func.__get__`, and at that point you're better off reading the descriptor howto than trying to dig it apart yourself.

One last thing: As brandizzi pointed out, this is something you almost never want to do. Alternatives include: Write `aFunction` as a free function instead of a method, so you just call `b.aFunction()`; factor out a function that does the real work, and have `A.aFunction` and `B.aFunction` just call it; have `B` aggregate an `A` and forward to it; etc.

Answer (score 1):

I already posted an answer to the question you asked. But you shouldn't have had to get down to the level of having to understand `new.instancemethod` to solve your problem. The only reason that happened is because you asked the wrong question. Let's look at what you *should* have asked, and why.

> In PySide.QtGui, I want the list widget items to have methods to set the font and colors, and they don't seem to.

This is what you really want. There may well be an easy way to do this. And if so, that's the answer you want. Also, by starting off with this, you avoid all the comments about "What do you actually want to do?" or "I doubt this is appropriate for whatever you're trying to do" (which often come with downvotes—or, more importantly, with potential answerers just ignoring your question).

> Of course I could just write a function that takes a QListWidgetItem and call that function, instead of making it a method, but that won't work for me because *_*_.

I assume there's a reason that won't work for you. But I can't really think of a good one. Whatever line of code said this:

```
item.setColor(color)
```

would instead say this:

```
setItemColor(item, color)
```

Very simple.

Even if you need to, e.g., pass around a color-setting delegate with the item bound into it, that's almost as easy with a function as with a method. Instead of this:

```
delegate = item.setColor
```

it's:

```
delegate = lambda color: setItemColor(item, color)
```

So, if there *is* a good reason you need this to be a method, that's something you really should explain. And if you're lucky, it'll turn out you were wrong, and there's a much simpler way to do what you want than what you were trying.

> The obvious way to do this would be to get PySide to let me specify a class or factory function, so I could write a QListWidgetItem subclass, and every list item I ever deal with would be an instance of that subclass. But I can't find any way to do that.

This seems like something that should be a feature of PySide. So maybe it is, in which case you'd want to know. And if it isn't, and neither you nor any of the commenters or answerers can think of a good reason it would be bad design or hard to implement, you should go file a feature request and it might be in the next version. (Not that this helps you if you need to release code next week against the current version, but it's still worth doing.)

> Since I couldn't find a way to do that, I tried to find some way to add my `setColor` method to the `QListWidgetItem` class, but couldn't think of anything.

Monkey-patching classes is very simple:

```
QListWidgetItem.setColor = setItemColor
```

If you didn't know you could do this, that's fine. If people knew that's what you were trying to do, this would be the first thing they'd suggest. (OK, maybe not many Python programmers know much about monkey-patching, but it's still a lot more than the number who know about descriptors or `new.instancemethod`.) And again, besides being an answer you'd get faster and with less hassle, it's a better answer.

Even if you did know this, some extension modules won't let you do that. If you tried and it failed, explain what didn't work instead:

> PySide wouldn't let me add the method to the class; when I try monkey-patching, *_*_.

Maybe someone knows why it didn't work. If not, at least they know you tried.

> So I have to add it to every instance.

Monkey-patching instances looks like this:

```
myListWidgetItem.setColor = setItemColor
```

So again, you'd get a quick answer, and a better one.

But maybe you knew that, and tried it, and it didn't work either:

> PySide also wouldn't let me add the method to each instance; when I try, *_*_.
>
> So I tried patching out the `__class__` of each instance, to make it point to a custom subclass, because that works in PyQt4, but in PySide it *_*_.

This probably won't get you anything useful, because it's just the way PySide works. But it's worth mentioning that you tried.

> So, I decided to create that custom subclass, then copy its methods over, like so, but *_*_.

And all the way down here is where you'd put all the stuff you put in your original question. If it really were necessary to solving your problem, the information would be there. But if there were an easy solution, you wouldn't get a bunch of confused answers from people who were just guessing at how `new.instancemethod` works.

Answer (score 0):

If possible you can make the `aFunction` unbound by using `@staticmethod` decorator: -

```
class A(object):
    @staticmethod
    def aFunction(B):    # Modified to take appropriate parameter..
        pass

class B(object): 
    pass

b = B()
b.aFunction = new.instancemethod(A.aFunction, b, B.__class__)
b.aFunction()
```

*NOTE: - You need to modify the method to take appropriate parameter..

Comment: I don't think this answers what the OP is asking. More importantly, your `aFunction` isn't actually "Modified to take appropriate parameter". There's nothing special about the name `B` you've given it. It definitely doesn't have anything to do with the class named `B`. It's just adding to the confusion.

Comment: To clarify why it doesn't answer what the OP is asking: "I'm not sure how I can get aFunction to allow itself to be applied to an instance of B". Making `aFunction` static doesn't allow itself to be applied to an instance of anything. It just happens to work out that an `instancemethod` made out of a static method will allow this, but that's really just something you got by accident. And meanwhile, the original `A.aFunction` can't be called on A instances.

Comment: @abarnet.. Yeah didn't actually noticed that thing.. Actually saw your answer and then realised that `descriptors` might be used, but I have still confusion in how descriptors work.. **Still new to Python :)

Comment: If the OP were clearer about what he's actually trying to accomplish (and why he needs to call `new.instancemethod`), it would be easier to answer… Anyway, there are ways to do this without directly dealing with descriptors, but you're just fooling yourself if you do, because `new.instancemethod` is essentially all about descriptors.

Comment: Yes, I just noticed the problem with this is that now I cannot use A.aFunction() - it's stopped being an instance method.

Answer (score 0):

I'm amazed that none of these answers gives what seems the simplest solution, specifically where you want an existing instance to have a method x replaced by a method x (same name) from another class (e.g. subclass) by being "grafted" on to it.

I had this issue in the very same context, i.e. with PyQt5. Specifically, using a `QTreeView` class, the problem is that I have subclassed `QStandardItem` (call it `MyItem`) for all the tree items involved in the tree structure (first column) and, among other things, adding or removing such an item involves some extra stuff, specifically adding a key to a dictionary or removing the key from this dictionary.

Overriding `appendRow` (and `removeRow`, `insertRow`, `takeRow`, etc.) presents no problem:

```
class MyItem( QStandardItem ):
    ...

    def appendRow( self, arg ):
        # NB QStandarItem.appendRow can be called either with an individual item 
        # as "arg", or with a list of items 
        if isinstance( arg, list ):
            for element in arg:
                assert isinstance( element, MyItem )
                self._on_adding_new_item( element )
        elif isinstance( arg, MyItem ):
            self._on_adding_new_item( arg )
        else:
            raise Exception( f'arg {arg}, type {type(arg)}')
        super().appendRow( self, arg )
```

... where `_on_adding_new_item` is a method which populates the dictionary.

The problem arises when you want to want to add a "level-0" row, i.e. a row the parent of which is the "invisible root" of the `QTreeView`. Naturally you want the items in this new "level-0" row to cause a dictionary entry to be created for each, but how to get this invisible root item, class `QStandardItem`, to do this?

I tried overriding the model's method `invisibleRootItem()` to deliver not `super().invisibleRootItem()`, but instead a new `MyItem`. This didn't seem to work, probably because `QStandardItemModel.invisibleRootItem()` does things behind the scenes, e.g. setting the item's `model()` method to return the `QStandardItemModel`.

The solution was quite simple:

```
class MyModel( QStandardItemModel ):
    def __init__( self ):
        self.root_item = None
        ...

    ...

    def invisibleRootItem( self ):
        # if this method has already been called we don't need to do our modification
        if self.root_item != None:
            return self.root_item 

        self.root_item = super().invisibleRootItem()
        # now "graft" the method from MyItem class on to the root item instance
        def append_row( row ):
            MyItem.appendRow( self.root_item, row  )
        self.root_item.appendRow = append_row
```

... this is not quite enough, however: `super().appendRow( self, arg )` in `MyItem.appendRow` will then raise an Exception when called on the root item, because a `QStandardItem` has no `super()`. Instead, `MyItem.appendRow` is changed to this:

```
def appendRow( self, arg ):
    if isinstance( arg, list ):
        for element in arg:
            assert isinstance( element, MyItem )
            self._on_adding_new_item( element )
    elif isinstance( arg, MyItem ):
        self._on_adding_new_item( arg )
    else:
        raise Exception( f'arg {arg}, type {type(arg)}')
    QStandardItem.appendRow( self, arg )
```

Answer (score -1):

Thanks Rohit Jain - this is the answer:

```
import new

class A(object):
    @staticmethod
    def aFunction(self):
        pass

#Class which doesn't support typecasting
class B(object): 
    pass

b = B()
b.aFunction = new.instancemethod(A.aFunction, b, B.__class__)
b.aFunction()
```

Comment: But that code will not work. As you are passing parameter to `aFunction`, whereas you haven't defined it to take one.. You need to work that around.. I have just given solution to your existing problemm

Comment: -1. I realize you're the OP, but your "fix" makes `aFunction` not work on `A` instances anymore, because it's a `@staticmethod` but takes a `self` parameter. If you wanted that, why even declare it in A instead of making it a free function?